# copy-webpack-plugin with fonts from /node_modules

Tags: webpack

I've an Angular application which uses webpack as module bundler.
This application also uses some assets (images, fonts, styles) from some other projects which are imported as node_modules.

The structure of my application is something like this

```
src/
  app/
    ...
  stylesheets/
    application.scss
```

Now, in my scss I have some references to images `src="/images/..."`, which are in node_modules/my_assets/images, so I used copy-webpack-plugin to include the images in bundle time

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  { from: 'node_modules/my-assets/images', to: 'images' },
  { from: 'node_modules/my-assets/favicons', to: 'favicons' },
```

This is working fine.

Problem now is with fonts. I have the same structure, but when the stylesheet references a font is now with a relative url `./fonts/Open-Sans-300/Open-Sans-300.eot`

So I tried to do the same as before

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  { from: 'node_modules/my-assets/images', to: 'images' },
  { from: 'node_modules/my-assets/favicons', to: 'favicons' },
  { from: 'node_modules/my-assets/fonts', to: 'fonts' }
])
```

This is not working. If I copy manually the /fonts folder directly in my /src/stylesheets folder it works fine. I'm guessing that as it's relative I'm not copying the folder where I have to, so I tried many variations:

```
{ from: 'node_modules/my-assets/fonts', to: '/fonts' },
{ from: 'node_modules/my-assets/fonts', to: './fonts' },
{ from: 'node_modules/my-assets/fonts', to: 'src/stylesheets/fonts' },
{ from: 'node_modules/my-assets/fonts', to: '/src/stylesheets/fonts' }
```

None of these work. Any idea why not? And what should I write instead?

I should also mention that I have a loader for the fonts

```
{ 
 test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, 
 loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
}
```

which seems to work fine.

EDIT: I must also say that this problem happens when using webpack-dev-server, so I don´t really know where is webpack copying the files when doing something like this `{ from: 'node_modules/my-assets/images', to: 'images' }`

Thanks

Comment: I added the loader for the fonts. I don´t think the rest of the webpack config is relevant. Also for the stylesheet it's just as I said in the description, it's requiring fonts this way ```./fonts/Open-Sans-300/Open-Sans-300.eot```

Comment: do you want to have the actual build as well as the webpack-dev-server?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want your SASS files to be able to resolve paths to statics assets like images or fonts, `CopyWebpackPlugin` is not the tool for you.

Given your font and SCSS loaders in place, Webpack should be able to build the dependencies tree by itself.

Remove `CopyWebpackPlugin` setting from your Webpack configuration and make sure to explicitly set the [output.publicPath](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-publicpath) setting.

```
output: {
  publicPath: '/',
  /* follows your output config */
},
```

Since [Webpack `sass-loader` does not provide url rewriting](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/tree/v6.0.5#problems-with-url), you have to tell webpack to rewrite them accordingly to the place where the assets are moved after the build.

Webpack [`resolve-url-loader`](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader)  plugin does exactly that. Place it directly after the sass-loader in the CSS loader chain and you should be ready to go.

```
{
    test   : /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
}
```

### Side note

[copy-webpack-plugin docs](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin#this-doesnt-copy-my-files-with-webpack-dev-server), clearly explain why the plugin doesn't copy files with webpack-dev-server:

> Starting in version 3.0.0, we stopped using fs to copy files to the filesystem and started depending on webpack's [in-memory filesystem](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#content-base):
>
> > ... webpack-dev-server will serve the static files in your build folder. It’ll watch your source files for changes and when changes are made the bundle will be recompiled. This modified bundle is served from memory at the relative path specified in publicPath (see API). It will not be written to your configured output directory.
>
> If you must have webpack-dev-server write to your output directory, you can force it with the [write-file-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/gajus/write-file-webpack-plugin).

Comment: In production my code works fine as it is, with ```{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['raw-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
      },``` and I don´t have to worry about the assets as they're properly deployed. Problem comes when using webpack-dev-server as my assets are only in node_modules.
I managed to get them copied but for some reason it's not working; I think the problem is with  the relative url in the fonts

Comment: I updated the loader example in order to show you how to let webpack move static resource into the build folder for you.

Since you are using `raw-loader`, Webpack won't parse the CSS files looking for further static assets, but will import as it is lie a black box. That's why you had to manually move your fonts like in the good old GruntJS times!

Replace your `raw-loader` with the `css-loader` and `style-loader` combo, and Webpack with move any static asset referenced in your CSS to your build folder.

Comment: Not working. Problem is, as I said in my previous comment, that when I use webpack-dev-server my assets are NOT where they are supposed to be. In production these asset are also deployed and as you said everything works fine if my ```output.publicPath``` is configured, but in development my images or fonts are not in /images or /fonts, they are imported as a dependency and stored in /node_modules, that's why I need to copy them to a temporary folder (just in development) for them to work. So it's a problem of webpack finding the assets. Changing the loader does not have any effect.

Comment: "place it directly after sass-loader".. places it directly before :/